# php to batch and back to php

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

The following batch code (the file is named `autoFTP.bat`) will rename the files from a folder:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::---------- Path to files that must be renamed
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b D:\folder\*.htm') do (
::---------- Path to md5sums.exe
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%j in ('md5sums -n -b "%%i"') do (
set number=%%i
set file=%%j
set file=!file:*.htm=!
for %%k in (!file!) do (
ren "%%i" "%%k.htm"
echo "!number! %%k"
)
)
)
echo.
```

In `update.php`, I would like to run the batch file and get the results (the old and new names of the files) in the php file. The `update.php` contains:

```
$fileName = exec("cmd /c D:\folder\autoFTP.bat", $out);

foreach($out as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

From what I read in the php manual, `$out` should be an array of results, but `$line` is empty.

The idea, in theory, is that I would like to update in DB the names of the files that are renamed (not the files, but only the renamed names of the files). So in order to do this I would like that the `$out` variable to contain the original name of the file as well as the renamed one.

If I run the `autoFTP.bat` independently from cmd, it will work correctly; but when I try calling it from `update.php`, it does nothing.

I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Sure it runs the bat file? try-catch it and chech if an error shows up. Check logs. Remember you are trying to run a bat file with the user running the apache process.